# Best practice of developing web application for both Nw.js and web version in one gitlab project

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, node-webkit

I am developing a web application (using react) and the project is quite huge for me (more than 100 files). Recently, I need to build the front-end part of that application using NW.js and deploy it for Windows.

I am struggling with how to maintain two versions of the same application in one GitLab project. As the code base of two versions is almost the same but just some function is different now. For example, to download or read a file in NW.js, it needs to call the function provided by Nw.js or other native calls. For further development, there may be some feature which is only for nw.js version.

The following is the suggestion that I can think of.

1. Developing using two branches in the git lab project. For every
   release, GitLab cli would build both versions of different
   branch.
2. Specify two Webpack configurations and environment variables for different versions of the application. For example, file A, B, C, D is for Web version and file A, B, C, E is for NW.js version. For every release, GitLab cli would use two Webpack files to build two bundle.js.

For the disadvantage of 1, when I need to add a new feature, I need to do it twice as I need to develop that feature in different branches where choice 2 share more file and function.

For Choice 2, The code may be more complex if the difference between the two versions becomes large.

I am struggling with two choices. Does anyone have any ideas? Or suggest some articles for me to decide. Any best practice to develop in such an application?

Answer (score 0):

If just some functions are different :

```
const desktopApp = Boolean(window && window.nw)
if (desktopApp) {
    //call function for version A
} else {
    //call function for version B
```